# Sequential mining technique for categorical events?

Tags: sequential-analysis, sequential-pattern-mining

I'm facing a problem where I have a short (2-8) sequence of discrete events, of variable length, and a final state. Ex.: cold, warm, warm -> soft clothing.

I would like to determine what are the main factors that lead to that final state and their timespan to the final state (previous ex: cold, length 2).

What can I use for this task?

I used traditional APriori, but it only gives me the confidence of the co-occurrence.